# What variant phrases of 五里不同天 exist?

Tags: phrase-request

**五里不同天** is defined in《广安方言与民俗词典》as:

> 比喻地区不同，事物就有差异。

I remember long ago hearing that in 福建 they say that the culture changes every nine *li*, but I never learned the actual phrase.

What similar phrases exist? I'm afraid that 广安方言 might not be all that universal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "十里不同音，百里不同俗"

Means different dialect every ten *li* / culture every hundred *li*

Basically the same methodology to describe how things are varies in such small geologic differences.  Also I believe "天" in "五里不同天" refers to the weather / climate (weather and climate are 2 different thing but I can't tell which one fits better here)

Comment: I also think it's plausible  "天" in "五里不同天" refers to the weather / climate.

Answer (score 2):

I am a Cantonese, and I've never heard of "五里不同天". However, I do know a similar phrase "各處鄉村各處例" (each village has its own custom/rule), also means *地区不同，事物就有差异*

I also heard the phrase '一方水土養一方人' (different area raise different people) on some Chinese documentary shows